# Creating Powershell script to remove unique value in a csv file

Tags: file, powershell, csv

Here after my problem:

I have a csv file which look like:

```
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"Enrolled User";"Device ID"
"xmipodusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPod Enrolment User""";"16"
"xmipodusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPod Enrolment User""";"18"
"xmipodusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPod Enrolment User""";"20"
"xmipadusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPad Enrolment User""";"22"
"xmtest02@arnaud.biz ""xmtest02""";"26"
"xmtest01@arnaud.biz ""xmtest01""";"46"
"xmipaden@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPad Enrolment User""";"61"
"xmipodusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPod Enrolment User""";"62"
"martind@arnaud.biz ""Martin Dupont - Head of IT Service Delivery""";"66"
"xmtest01@arnaud.biz ""xmtest01""";"70"
"xmipodusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPod Enrolment User""";"75"
"xmipodusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPod Enrolment User""";"76"
"xmipodusa@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPod Enrolment User""";"80"
"xmtest01@arnaud.biz ""xmtest01""";"81"
"xmtest01@arnaud.biz ""xmtest01""";"83"
"xmipaden@arnaud.biz ""XenMobile Shared iPad Enrolment User""";"88"
"rogerd@arnaud.biz ""Roger Durand - Head of HR""";"89"
```

I would like to create a script to remove the unique value and keep only the values that are present more than once (based on 1st column, "Enrolled User")in the csv file.

Thanks for any input/help.

Cheers,
Arnaud

Answer (score 3):

I would use the `Group-Object` cmdlet

```
Import-Csv -Path $FileName -Delimiter ';' |
    Group-Object -Property "Enrolled User" |
    Where-Object Count -gt 1 |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group |
    Export-Csv -Path $NewFileName -Delimiter ';'
```

Also, note that you can remove the `#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject` stuff when exporting a CSV by specifying the `-NoTypeInformation` parameter on `Export-Csv`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, it works like a charm ;)